# Java- Cannot import JIprolog packages

Tags: java, prolog, jiprolog

In Java I use these imports:

```
import com.ugos.jiprolog.engine.JIPEngine;
import com.ugos.jiprolog.engine.JIPQuery;
import com.ugos.jiprolog.engine.JIPSyntaxErrorException;
import com.ugos.jiprolog.engine.JIPTerm;
import com.ugos.jiprolog.engine.JIPTermParser;
```

And I have downloaded [JIProlog](http://www.jiprolog.com/) and exported it in my project directory.
However when I try to compile my java file (Communicator.java) like this:

```
javac -cp JIProlog/jipconsole.jar:. Communicator.java
```

I get an error:

```
package com.ugos.jiprolog.engine does not exist
```

Have I skipped a step or something?